# Read access violation. _Mycont was nullptr error while getting udp data into vectors in C++

Tags: c++, udp, access-violation

I read this error posts I get the idea in which case does this error occur, however I try to find this situations in my code but I am struggling to detect what is the cause of the problem.

Overall code explanation:

I take UDP packets from ethernet and parse my user created header to see whether we have a lost fragment(packet) or not by counting the number of lost fragments. (`lostFragmentCount++`) While doing this I concat data(packet) in array in my while loop. `FrameFragmentNo` and `PrevFrameFragmentNo` can be considered as pointers to trace frame to detect lost fragment.

The problematic part is  after this line `concatAry.insert(it+intData.size(),GetIntArrayFromByteArray(vec).begin(), GetIntArrayFromByteArray(vec).end());`

At his line I get *Exception thrown: read access violation. _Mycont was nullptr.* error. When it calls `GetIntArrayFromByteArray()` method for the 3rd time. (It does not give error int he first place)

I put breakpoints to trace the size of those array while doing conversion, it looks correct, I suspect maybe when we take huge data from ethernet while taking data, it might overflow but if this was the case buffer should give error before getting into while.

**The problem may stem from `insert()` method usage**. I am trying to figure out.

I couldn't understand why after some time(nth iteration while getting data from ethernet) I get this error. Does anybody have an idea?

> related variables

```
char buf[1550];//message gets here
```

> Here is my while loop that takes udp packet strips(shifts) user
>   created header to save rest of the data:

```
while (true)
        {
            ZeroMemory(&client, clientLength); // Clear the client structure
            ZeroMemory(buf, 1550); // Clear the receive buffer

            // Wait for message
            int bytesIn = recvfrom(in, buf, 1550, 0, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientLength);

            if (bytesIn == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "Error receiving from client " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                continue;
            }


            if (FrameFragmentNo == 1 && SkipFrameFlag == 1)  // After the skip flag, catch the start of frame.
            {
                SkipFrameFlag = 0;
                PrevFrameFragmentNo = 0;
                //Array.Clear(intData, 0, intData.Length);
            }

            if (FrameFragmentNo != (PrevFrameFragmentNo + 1)) //Fragment is lost. Skip Frame
            {
                SkipFrameFlag = 1;
                lostFragmentCount++;
            }


            if (SkipFrameFlag == 1)
                continue;

            //skip user created header
            int shift = 14;
            int length = sizeof(buf);
            memmove(buf, buf + shift, length - shift);
            memset(buf + length - shift, '0', shift);

            //char buf ----> vecor<char> vec
            int n = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf);//number of elements
            vector<char> vec(buf, buf + n);


            //Write data into a file 
            filePutContents("C:\\Users\\Dell\\UDPClientServerBasic\\UDP_Server\\UDP_Server\\recordings.txt", intData, true);


        }//end of while
```

> Here is the GetIntArrayFromCharArray() method

```
     vector<uint16_t> GetIntArrayFromCharArray(vector<char> arr)
        {
            // If the number of bytes is not even, put a zero at the end
            if ((arr.size() % 2) == 1)
                arr.resize(arr.size()+1);
            //arr.push_back(0);


            vector<uint16_t> intArray;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i += 2)
                intArray.push_back((uint16_t)((arr[i] << 8) | arr[i + 1]));

    /*arr[i + 1] gives warning saying "Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value 
and then casting the result to a 8 byte value." 

But I don't think this could be a issue since it is just for loop's iterator
    */
            return intArray;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The iterator `it = concatAry.begin();` is invalidated after the first insert. Use `concatAry.begin()` instead of `it` in the second insert:

```
concatAry.insert(concatAry.begin()+intData.size(),GetIntArrayFromCharArray(vec).begin(), , GetIntArrayFromCharArray(vec).end());
```

It seems you use `insert` when `std::copy` is assumed. Either use `std::copy` or remove sizing constructor before `insert` (use `vector<uint16_t> concatAry;` without size parameter).

Comment: I edited my code according to your suggestion however it gives error saying can not seek value initialized vector iterator, an invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

Comment: More details please. The exact code, the exact compiler message.

Comment: I added two pics, first one is before calling method, second is the inside of the method when error occurs; this is the exact code other parts are IP and client configuration which are not related

Comment: `it` is invalidated after the first call of the method `insert`. Why did you do `it + intData.size()` with the invalidated  `it` again?

Comment: Never edit the code in your initial question after got answers, just add updated information to your question. If you edit the initial question, then answers become unrelated to the edited question.

Comment: yes you are right, I'll change it to original code, "it" looks invalid all the time it never assigns,  I thought maybe before filling concat array, it behaves as null, even I put "it = concatAry.begin();"  after fill the concat array, it didn't work. Also I got rid of if else thing, I am trying to figure out why it behaves null